# datagridview in pygtk

Tags: pygtk, canonical-quickly

I'm Trying to find a way to teach Quickly platform to an highschool class who knows GDI on .net, so Im looking for a GDI DataGrid equivalent on pyGTK/Quickly.
Any suggestions?
tx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gtkTreeView is what I was looking for.